# What implementation changes should be done in maxcut code using VQE?

Tags: entanglement, circuit-construction

In the paper, ["Quantum algorithm implementations for beginners"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03719.pdf) in the section XVII. QUANTUM SIMULATION OF THE TRANSVERSE ISING MODEL (page 54-58), the authors have plotted energy $E$ vs magnetic field strength $h$ using two circuits, one without entanglement and one with entanglement.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why have only these circuits only  been used?
2. What implementation changes can I make in the maxcut code using VQE to obtain the above graph? I am trying to change the RY package which is used in the code to change the circuit. In the paper fig 51.(c), the depth of the circuit is 1. Does that mean to increase the depth, I have to replicate the circuit in fig 51.(c) up to depth times? Can someone provide the code changes?